# Why does this index string clear the $_SESSION array?

Tags: php

Some weird behavior I've found - I'm intrigued - can anyone shed any light on this..?

**Overview**

Spent some time this morning finding the cause of a bug which was resulting in the `$_SESSION` array to empty. Eventually got to the bottom of it and found that when defining an index for one of the `$_SESSION` variables, an `&` was being used for concatination instead of a `.`. It only broke when two specific strings were `&`ed, other strings resulted in nonsense keys but `$_SESSION` didn't empty.

This is running on PHP5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 and locally on PHP5.6.15.

**Try it yourself!**

Using the example code below,

1. Run *set-session.php*
2. Run *check-session.php* - all good
3. Run *break-session.php* - still good so far...
4. Run *check-session.php* again - `$_SESSION` is now empty!

**Example code**

*set-session.php*

```
session_start();

$_SESSION = [
   'colour' => 'blue',
   'shape'  => 'round',
   'size'   => 'medium'
];
```

*check-session.php*

```
session_start();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
```

*break-session.php*

```
session_start();

$killer_string = 'Admin_CH_1_' & '101_';
$_SESSION[$killer_string] = null;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
```

**My guess**

I'm guessing that the result of the bitwise operation results in a string, in this case `$killer_string`, that causes PHP to get angry when it tries to store the `$_SESSION` array on the server. Strange that `$killer_string` is no longer a killer when used as a key for a sub array in `$_SESSION` though.

**Ideas?**

I know that the code doesn't actually make sense so there's no fault with PHP. However, I am curious as to what is actually going on behind the scenes and what's causing this...

Cheers!

Comment: Did you `var_dump($killer_string);`?  Yields `☺ !I`

Comment: What PHP version are you using? I just tested with 5.6.25 and `$killer_string` was set as an array key with a string similar to @AbraCadaver

Comment: I have the same result as @MichaelBerkowski in php-7

Comment: Updated question with versions I get this on.

Comment: There are also some bug reports in the bug tracker reporting this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simplified test case ([see it in action](https://3v4l.org/lJXoP)):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
ob_start();

session_start();
$_SESSION = [
    'colour'               => 'blue',
    'shape'                => 'round',
    'size'                 => 'medium',
    //'Admin_CH_1_' & '101_' => 'Gone',
    chr(0x01) . chr(0x20) . chr(0x21) . chr(0x49) => 'Gone',
];
var_dump($_SESSION);
session_write_close();

session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
ob_end_flush();
```

If you inspect the session file you can see it has zero bytes.

My best guess so far (until someone smarter shares a link to the PHP github repo with the specific internals) is that you are inadvertently pushing the limits of the session serialization code. Such code assumes that keys are non-binary strings. There's certain validation (pure numeric keys trigger a *Skipping numeric key* notice) but it doesn't cover all possible malformed inputs. At some point it just crashes.

This gets supported by the fact that changing the serialisation method *fixes* the issue:

```
ini_set('session.serialize_handler', 'php_serialize');
```

In the [`session.serialize_handler` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler) we can read:

> Older serialize handlers cannot store numeric index nor string index
>   contains special characters (| and !) in `$_SESSION`. Use
>   `php_serialize` to avoid numeric index or special character errors at
>   script shutdown. Defaults to `php`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Turns out this behaviour is already on SO, is just a tricky thing to search for!